# Passing in parameters to promise.done() after AJAX call

Tags: ajax

I know there are lots of AJAX questions out there, but after reading through them wasn't able to figure out how to do this (I'm new to JS)

Pass in the $form variable (or other variables) to the ajaxFormSubmitSuccess function, in addition to the "data variable" that gets returned by the ajax call (which you could access by `.done(function(data){});` ...not really sure what type of object it is).

I have (this doesn't work):

```
//handles ajax form submissions
$("form[data-ccajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);

var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {

var $form = $(this);
var options = {
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    type: $form.attr("method"),
    context: this,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType: "html"
};

//send ajax command
var promise = $.ajax(options);
promise.done(ajaxFormSubmitSuccess($form, promise));
promise.fail(ajaxFormSubmitFailure);
return false;

}
```

Right now the `.done(ajaxFormSubmitSuccess($form, promise));` code calls the function below. the `data` variable doesn't get extracted from `promise`...so `$data` remains null throughout the code.

```
var ajaxFormSubmitSuccess = function ($form, $promise) {

var $data;
$promise.success(function (data) { $data = data; });

alert("succeededajaxFormSubmit");

var target1 = $("#"+$form.attr('data-cctarget1'));
target1.html($data);

}
```

Any help on how to do this right is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$promise` inside the `ajaxFormSubmitSuccess` is not the result of the ajax call but a promise. It's async so that's why your variable `$data` is still empty after `$promise.success()`.

Try this way:

```
var ajaxFormSubmitSuccess = function ($form, $promise) 
{
    $promise.success(function (data) 
    {
        alert("succeededajaxFormSubmit");

        var target1 = $("#"+$form.attr('data-cctarget1'));
        target1.html(data);
    });
}
```

For more insights: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Thank you - that seems to work - I had assumed ajaxFormSubmitSuccess would only be called (even though JS is async) after the request was "done" & "data" was populated...guess not.